# how to convert unicode to iso using an xml data source in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Need to convert all unicode(&#x007E;) of an XML to iso(&tilde;) from an XML(entities.xml) where all these values are stroed....

entities.xml:-

```
<entities>
<entity iso="eacute" unicode="x00e9"/>
<entity iso="iacute" unicode="x00ed"/>
</entities>
```

Input:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter>
<title>Chapt&#x00e9;r Tilt&#x00e9;</title>
<body>
    <p>Th&#x00ed;s is t&#x00e9;xt...</p>
    <p>Th&#x00ed;s is t&#x00e9;xt...</p>
    <p>Th&#x00ed;s is t&#x00e9;xt...</p>
    <p>Th&#x00ed;s is t&#x00e9;xt...</p>
    <p>Th&#x00ed;s is t&#x00e9;xt...</p>
</body>    
</chapter>
```

Output should be :-

```
<chapter>
<title>Chapt&eacute;r Tilt&eacute;</title>
<body>
    <p>Th&iacute;s is t&eacute;xt...</p>
    <p>Th&iacute;s is t&eacute;xt...</p>
    <p>Th&iacute;s is t&eacute;xt...</p>
    <p>Th&iacute;s is t&eacute;xt...</p>
    <p>Th&iacute;s is t&eacute;xt...</p>
</body>
```

There are many other values are also in entities.xml like....

```
    <entity iso="nbsp" unicode="x00a0"/>
<entity iso="ordf" unicode="x00aa"/>
<entity iso="ordm" unicode="x00ba"/>
<entity iso="para" unicode="x00b6"/>
<entity iso="plusmn" unicode="x00b1"/>
<entity iso="pound" unicode="x00a3"/>
<entity iso="raquo" unicode="x00bb"/>
<entity iso="reg" unicode="x00ae"/>
<entity iso="sect" unicode="x00a7"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using xslt-2.0 using character-map.

Try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:character-map name="CharMap">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#x00ed;" string="&amp;iacute;"/>
        <xsl:output-character character="&#x00e9;" string="&amp;eacute;"/>
    </xsl:character-map>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" use-character-maps="CharMap"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: what about entities.xml data file which containing all the values of entities....
<entities>
    <entity iso="tilde" unicode="x007E"/>
    <entity iso="lsquo" unicode="x2018"/>
    <entity iso="ldquo" unicode="x201c"/>
    <entity iso="rsquo" unicode="x2019"/>
</entities>

Comment: If I were you, I would find and replace using regex to convert that to an xsl file e.g. `<xsl:character-map name="CharMap"><xsl:output-character character="&#x007E;" string="&amp;tilde;"/><xsl:output-character character="&#x2018;" string="&amp;lsquo;"/></xsl:character-map name="CharMap">` and so forth.

Comment: Then save that as entities.xsl. Afterwards, use `xsl:include` to include that in your stylesheet.